# Multiple IP addresses being assigned

Tags: raspbian, networking, dhcp

My Raspberry Pi B+ is running Raspbian (Linux version 3.18.11+) updated, etc.

It's connected to the network by ethernet. I want a static IP, and have assigned it one in /etc/network/interfaces (shown below). However, every boot it requests an address via DHCP and is assigned one! Both the static and dynamic addresses work to access the machine on the network.

Where can I stop the DHCP address from being requested and assigned??

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

ip addr show eth0

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:44:bb:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.1.55/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:44:bb:23  
          inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11484 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4178807 (3.9 MiB)  TX bytes:4019638 (3.8 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

Comment: Can you tell us output of ifconfig ?

Comment: added ifconfig above

Comment: My bad. I meant "ifconfig -a". Can you modify your log above ?

Comment: The output with the -a flag is identical to above.

Comment: What's is the content of wpa_supplicant.conf ?

Comment: wpa_supplicant.conf added above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue.

I assume you are using 2015-05-05 build of Rasbian.  In this build, the static IP is set in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

You should:

1. Revert your changes in `/etc/network/interfaces` back to default
2. Put the ip information in your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to configure a static IP, replacing whatever your interface is for `wlan0`
3. Reboot

--

```
# what I did
# this goes in /etc/dchpcd.conf for static ip assignment 
interface wlan0
 static ip_address=10.3.2.8/24
 static routers=10.3.2.1
 static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

**before**

```
$ ip addr
.... <snip>
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:4e:06:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.3.2.8/24 brd 10.3.2.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.3.2.101/24 brd 10.3.2.255 scope global secondary wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**after**

```
$ ip addr
.... <snip>
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:4e:06:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.3.2.8/24 brd 10.3.2.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

These links are where I found my answer:

- [Set Static IP address but also getting Dynamic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=111709)
- [Single static IP address for eth0](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=798866#p798866)

Comment: **Thank you, success!** I did have to remember to set eth0 to the new default of `manual` instead of the old default of `dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Debian Network Configuration documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) and [other documentation online](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/networkSchemes.html#hotpluggable), my understanding is that `allow-hotplug` is only necessary for removable network adapters, or if you're using dhcp on an adapter that might not be present at boot in order to avoid long dhcp timeouts. Try removing the `allow-hotplug eth0` line if you're using a static configuration.

I tried replicating your problem with several variations, but only obtained a single IP address as show with `ip addr`. Do you by any chance have anything under the various `/etc/network/if-*` directories?

Comment: if-down.d:
openvpn  resolvconf  upstart  wpasupplicant

if-post-down.d:
avahi-daemon  wireless-tools  wpasupplicant

if-pre-up.d:
wireless-tools  wpasupplicant

if-up.d:
000resolvconf  avahi-daemon  mountnfs  openssh-server  openvpn  upstart  wpasupplicant

Comment: commenting out the `allow-hotplug eth0` line has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could do to get a static IP (without all that) is to first find you MAC address by typing this:

> ifconfig eth0

and looking for HWaddr (and after that is your mac address). After that go onto your router admin page and go to DHPC or IP reservations (on my router it was in LAN setup). Then add the MAC address and choose and IP. You don't have to add the MAC address as most router's have the option to just pick the IP (the name will be the name you set in raspi-config hostname).

Will :3

ask questions

Comment: I put the command ifconfig eth0 for other users (I know you know)

Comment: That's a great (round-about) solution to this: adding the MAC address to the router's DHCP reservations. However, that won't work for this setup...

Comment: Yeh sorry, I just put it just in case you hadnt' thought of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had configured `x.x.x.250` in `/etc/network/interfaces` and was getting `x.x.x.20` as well, although that did not exist anywhere.

I'm using ethernet, and because I do not need dhcp I disabled the `dhcpcd` service as follows:

```
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

(Note that if you're doing this over SSH as I was, then the last command will probably hang your SSH. So <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a functioning local command prompt back then ssh in again.)

This seems to have worked for me.

Comment: The dhcp package could probably be purged too if you're not going to put the static IP in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Comment: i had the same problem. but did not want to delete the dhcpcd service. so i shutdown the raspi, pulled of the power cable, and started it again. the previously dynamically assigend ips finally disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to configure multiple interfaces:[Multiple IP addresses on one Interface](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface).

Comment: Can you edit your answer to summarise the contents of the link, in case of future link death. Thanks.